# Rename pentaho multiple .ktr files in my folder

Tags: pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

I have multiple .ktr transformation files in one of my folder. I've used spaces in the naming convention. So, I want to rename all those pentaho transformation files using "Spoon". Are there any steps that can rename all my files at once?

Example : I've file calles "Invoice Items.ktr".
I want to rename this file to "InvoiceItems.ktr".

Answer (score 1):

There isn't a step that does "Rename" action, you need to generate a new filename and move the file to itself.

You can use this with a series of steps for this.

EDIT:
In the get file names step, in the Wildcard column, use RegEx ".*", this will select all files within that folder. In the File/Directory column you leave only the directory, not the full filename.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks For your reply.This process only works for renaming one single transformation.How can we rename all files with in one single run.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks for your support.I really appreciate it.

Comment: Similary, can you also help me "how to remove a special character "&" from the filename. Example: I have file called "Task&Event.ktr" . I want to rename it to "TaskEvent" by removing the special character.

Comment: You can mark the answer as being the right answer, that helps other people with the same problem. For your second comment, remove characters, use the "Replace in String" step.